# Universal $W^*$-algebras of locally compact groups: where is the error in this argument?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.
It is known that $G$ can be topologically embedded in $W^{\ast}(G)$ , its universal $W^{\ast}$-algebra (with the $\sigma$-weak topology). An element $T \in W^{\ast}(G)$ is a function assigning to each representation $\pi$ a bounded operator $T(\pi) \in B(H_{\pi})$. This $T$ must be compatible with interwiners and $T(\pi)$ must be uniformly bounded.

This was done (in a slightly different language) by J. Ernest in [A new group algebra for locally compact groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/2373020).

Now define $G_{\otimes}= \{ T \in W^*(G)_{\neq 0} / T(\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2) = T(\pi_1) \otimes T(\pi_2) \}$

It's not hard to see that elements in $G_{\otimes}$ are unitaries. This is briefly proven in [Yuhjtman - Some considerations regarding the universal $W^*$ algebra of a topological group](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/Members/sergioyuhjtman/WG2.pdf) (proposition 4.2).

Now Tatsuuma's duality theorem applies ([Tatsuuma - A duality theorem for locally compact groups, I](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195522200), proposition 2) so $G=G_\otimes$. But $G_\otimes$ is closed and inside the unit ball, so it is compact (always $\sigma$-weak topolgy). Therefore $G$ is compact.

Comment: Why is $G_{\otimes}$ closed in the $\sigma$-weak topology?

Comment: Because the functional $<(-)(\pi) \alpha, \beta>$ is sigma-weakly continuous. This can be found in the first two links in the question.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "Where is the error?"

Comment: @Matt: this is instinctively where I think there might be a gap. In fact, isn't the closure going to be this Eberlein compactor action that Spronk-Stokke have been looking at?

Comment: That should have been "Eberlein compactification" ...

Comment: Is it not simply that you can have a net in $G_{\otimes}$ which converges $\sigma$-weakly to $0$?  So $\{0\} \cup G_{\otimes}$ is compact, and thus $G_{\otimes}$ is locally compact, and the problems disappear.  I have to say also that I'm not up to speed with Ernest's approach to $W^*(G)$, and I also don't really see how Tatsumma's work applies here...

Comment: The product condition may be a closed condition, but being non-zero doesn't look like a closed condition. So what we can say is  that $G_\otimes\cup \{ 0\}$ is closed.
That would mean, we get the one-point compactification, that's all.

Anyway, have you tried looking at the example $G$ equals the integers with the discrete topology?

Comment: Here http://cms.dm.uba.ar/Members/sergioyuhjtman/WG2.pdf/download (proposition 4.3) it is explained why $G_\otimes$ is closed, with special attention to $0$ not being in the closure.

Comment: Look at the group $G=\mathbb Z$ the integers. Every unitary representation of $G$ is a direct integral of one-dimensional representations, so it suffices to describe an element $T$ of $G_\otimes$ on irreducibles. The irreducible representations of $G$ can be identified with the unit circle, so $T$ can be viewed as a map from the unit circle to itself that is multiplicative, i.e., a group homomorphism. But why should it be continuous? It doesn't say so.
Tatsuma would say that $T$ needs to be of the form $T(z)=z^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, but that can only be deduced if $T$ is continuous.

Comment: I think this is wrong: "it suffices to describe an element $T$ of $G_\otimes$ on irreducibles" because $T$ might not commute with direct integrals. However, in case Tatsuuma is wrong, it is still possible to reach a contradiction. Thit is explained here: http://cms.dm.uba.ar/Members/sergioyuhjtman/WG2.pdf/download

Comment: $G_\otimes$ is not a group.  You make a mistake in your proof when you assume that for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space the map $\xi \otimes \overline{\eta} \mapsto \langle \xi, \eta \rangle$ extends to a bounded linear operator.

Comment: Since I agree with Martin's comment, I have changed the title. I also want to second @XognAmbandi's comments that the *first* thing that should have been tried is to apply the machinery to ${\mathbb Z}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A link to the literature: I think of $C^*(G)^*$ as being $B(G)$, the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra, realised as a (non-closed) algebra of continuous functions on $G$.  Any member of $C^*(G)^*$ can be realised as the composition of a representation $\pi$ on $H$ with a vector functional $\omega_{\xi,\eta}$ on $H$.  The resulting function in $B(G)$ is $g\mapsto (\pi(g)\xi|\eta)$.

Then $W^*(G)$ is $B(G)^*$.  As the tensor product of representations corresponds to the product in $B(G)$, it follows that $G_{\otimes}$ is actually just the collection of *characters* on $B(G)$, namely algebra homomorphisms $B(G)\rightarrow\mathbb C$.  Such things were explored by Walter in his paper ["On the structure of the Fourier–Stieltjes algebra"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102905857).

It's shown that $G_{\otimes}$ is not a group, and that it contains proper partial isometries and projections; it is a semigroup though.

Comment: This is a good reference, thank you! But the real answer is what Jesse Peterson said.

Comment: @Sergio, that seems a slightly unfair comment. Matthew has stated exactly the same reason that Jesse gave, namely that $G_\otimes$ is NOT a group, and he provides a link to a paper which shows this and gives details.

Comment: OK, I'll accept the answer to be polite and grateful (actually I want to thank everyone who got involved!) but I still think as before.

Comment: What @JessePeterson [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93873/universal-w-algebras-of-locally-compact-groups-where-is-the-error-in-this-a#comment241127_93873), referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93873/universal-w-algebras-of-locally-compact-groups-where-is-the-error-in-this-a#comment241236_93941).